# Using contact form 7 with easy fancybox

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

RESOLVED - funny how simply writing down a problem can help you think. It was just a setting "close fancybox when content is clicked". So sorry to waste time / space. Please feel free to delete this to save my blushes :)

I'm struggling to get contact form 7 work properly with easy fancybox in my custom template.

I have read and tried everything I can find on the internet, but the problem remains that while I can get my form to "popup" in fancybox, as soon as you try to type in a field it "pops" back down again - which isn't a lot of use!

Here's the code I am using:

```
<a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">Contact Us</a>
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
<div id="contact_form_pop">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="988" title="Contact"]'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

The weird thing is that it seems to work OK on regular wp posts, but not with my template. Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a simple setting option in the Fancybox settings: "close fancybox if content clicked"...
DOH